# How to join a query as a tabel in laravel form?

Tags: sql, laravel

Like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `teachers` AS t1 
    JOIN (SELECT ROUND(RAND() * ((SELECT MAX(id) FROM `teachers`)-(SELECT MIN(id) FROM `teachers`))+(SELECT MIN(id) FROM `teachers`)) AS id) AS t2 
    WHERE t1.id >= t2.id 
ORDER BY t1.id LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: Not really sure, but is this a weird drawn-out way to order your results randomly? If so, what's wrong with `Teacher::orderByRaw('RAND()')->take(20)->get();`? Also if I *am* right and it's a way to get a random 20 rows, it'll not always return 20 (or even any) rows - if you have gaps in the IDs then your function to select a random one won't work too well.

Comment: @alexrussell thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try raw in join.

```
Teacher::select(
        '*',

    )->join(
        DB::raw(SELECT ROUND(RAND() * ((SELECT MAX(id) FROM `teachers`)-(SELECT MIN(id) FROM `teachers`))+(SELECT MIN(id) FROM `teachers`)) AS id) ) as t2, t1.id >= t2.id
     )
    ->orderBy('t1.id')
     ->get();
```